# Converting multi-markdown to HTML & back in python

Tags: python, multimarkdown

Is there a python library for converting multimarkdown to HTML (python-markdown seem to have its own extensions). Further is there a library for converting a HTML into MMD?

Thank you,
Joseph

Comment: You can just shell out to the MMD binary using `subprocess.(p)open` if you need to convert from MMD --> HTML. There's no library to reverse the process.